# How to set a row always on top of table when sorting in primefaces?

Tags: java, sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable and I want a specific row always on top when I use sort. 
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own sort function as described in primefaces 4 guide pg. 140

**Managed Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AlwaysOnTopBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        //I want b to be always on top
        cars.add(new Car("b"));
        cars.add(new Car("a"));
        cars.add(new Car("c"));
    }

    public int sort(Object o1, Object o2) {

        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:carTable");

        SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.valueOf(dataTable.getSortOrder().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
        boolean asc = sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING);

        String m1 = o1.toString();
        String m2 = o2.toString();

        if (m2.equals("b")) {
            return (asc) ? 1 : -1;
        }

        return m1.compareToIgnoreCase(m2);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dataTable id="carTable" value="#{alwaysOnTopBean.cars}" var="car">
        <p:column sortBy="model" headerText="Model" sortFunction="#{alwaysOnTopBean.sort}" >
            #{car.model}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I found it, but I want to an element always in top, this solution will make one to top but when sort next time after, it'll go bottom of list :(